Problem in compiling pjsip in visual studio
i was initially trying to compile microsip and it required pjsip so im trying to compile pjsip using visual studio and the build instructions on the site. currently facing these errors after initially it wasnt detecting sdl header files despite me adding them in include and library path in the project properties. i simply copied the sdl header files to the directory of pjmedia. now its not finding the openh264.lib file but searching online is yielding no results
